# How would I get total disk space used by all MySQL databases beginning with a certain prefix?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio

I have a server with a lot of MySQL databases on it. They are setup with prefixes, such as `"DB1-2939128"` and `"DB2-3193831"`. I am working on a c# project and am trying to calculate the total disk size of all databases beginning with one of the prefixes. For example:

```
58.29MB of disk space is used by all databases beginning with "DB1-"
```

I have been searching the web and have not found any c# examples. The best I have found is the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT table_schema "Database Name",
       SUM(data_length+index_length)/1024/1024 "Database Size (MB)"
FROM information_schema.TABLES
GROUP BY table_schema;
```

This would return the total size of all databases though, and not just the ones with a particular prefix. I'm also not quite sure how to implement this into c#.

Please be kind, I am new here. If you could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You've adopted `frostbyte`,  the online name of one of the greatest programmers of all time, Kevin McCormick of blessed memory.  Frostbyte graduated from MIT in 1999 and died untimely in 2006. May your use of his name honor his memory!

Comment: @O.Jones, I did not know that but hope that my use of it will indeed honor his memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. You want to add `WHERE ... LIKE 'prefix%'` and then use `SUBSTRING()` in your `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(table_schema,1, LENGTH('wp')) "Database Name Prefix", 
       SUM(data_length+index_length)/1024/1024     "Database Size (MB)"
  FROM information_schema.TABLES
 WHERE table_schema LIKE CONCAT('wp', '%')
 GROUP BY SUBSTRING(table_schema,1, LENGTH('WP'))
```

Or if you want the databases itemized, it's this.

```
SELECT table_schema "Database Name Prefix", 
       SUM(data_length+index_length)/1024/1024     "Database Size (MB)"
  FROM information_schema.TABLES
 WHERE table_schema LIKE CONCAT(prefix', '%')
 GROUP BY table_schema WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Thank you so much @O.Jones! This is great and should help me with the project I am working on. I appreciate your quick response. :)